# file editor, PHP, " problem

Tags: php, file, post, text-editor, parse-error

I have a code that takes $_POST var. However, this var may sometimes include some *"*, therefore it makes the var end, and it's not complete, so my editor only sends a part of file.
Is there any way **how i can make " and ' being replaced before processed** so it won't end my var?

Answer (score 0):

Before you send it to your editor, run it through [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php).

Comment: This doesn't help. My file ended anyway.. I need it to replace ' and " with \' and \"

Comment: I think I misunderstood the problem... are you saying that you need to deal with the slashes *before* it gets to the php code?

Comment: I need to get ' and " replaced with \' and \" so i can send it to another script which turns it back into ' and " and puts it back inside a file. Now it just modifies " to \\\" and if there is ', nothing happens.

Comment: I think we're going to need to see some code in order to tell you what's wrong...

Comment: I know what's wrong, the problem is, that ' and " in $_POST['file'] must become replaced by \' and \". So when $_POST['file'] is: Do it! Let's become exc"ited!, it will become Do it! Let\'s become exc\"ited!

Answer (score 0):

Variables in memory arent terminated with " marks.
If you need to reference " in your code, you can try doing \" so for example

```
$test = "Hello \"world\"";
```

would be Hello "World"

Answer (score 0):

[htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
<input type="text" name="some" 
 value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['some'],ENT_QUOTES);?>"
```